# A movie where everyone in the line of presidential succession is killed in a terrorist attack and a mailman becomes POTUS

Tags: story-identification, movie

The title is pretty much self-describing. I have no idea who the actors are, and it might have been a comedy - I only vaguely remember it as the last time I saw it was 4 or 5 years ago. It came up in a conversation, and I want to rewatch it, but I have no idea how to find it.

Comment: Maybe someone can migrate this to Movie & TV SE?

Comment: What part of this has SFF elements?

Comment: @iMerchant From M&TV's point of view, this question as it stands would be considered low-quality enough to fall under the golden rule of migration. Perhaps the OP would like to repost it on [movies.se] after reading that site's quality guidelines on ID questions (see the "Identify-This-X Questions" section at the bottom of [this page](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic); basically, **provide more details**).

Comment: @DJMethaneMan. Are you sure it was a terrorist attack that killed off POTUS and the successors and not some apocalyptic event?  If so, then I would agree with the others this needs to be closed/moved. Otherwise, you might see if this does match the movie the Postman which I listed below.  It is a long shot as it is definitely not a comedy. But, does have some comedic moments you might be remembering.

Comment: @beichst Yes, a terrorist attack for sure - it was a very important detail. The landscape wasnt very post apocalyptic

Comment: @Randal'Thor Perhaps you can explain how it is off-topic - maybe it lacks some content, but I can edit that in (eg the movie was made in 2000's, maybe late 90's).

Comment: @DJMethaneMan From the description of the film you've given, it's not clear that there's anything sci-fi or fantasy about it. And if it's not sci-fi or fantasy, then it must be off-topic here.

Comment: @Mooz Not all science fiction and fantasy is set in the distant future or distant past.

Comment: @DJMethaneMan That's correct, and we're not looking for the movie's timeline per se, rather what parts or elements of it had any sort of science-fiction or fantasy to it? For example: [White House Down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_House_Down) was set in present time and had no Sci-Fi elements (therefore off-topic here), whereas [Iron Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Man_(2008_film)) was also set in present times, but had a lot of Sci-Fi elements (therefore on-topic here). Hope this helps clarify what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the 1997 post-apocalyptic Kevin Costner film [The Postman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Postman_(film)) based on the novel of the same name by David Brin.

In the novel and movie after an unnamed apocalyptic event a nomadic drifter who lived stumbles across the uniform of an old United States Postal Service mail carrier.  He tries to survive by masquerading as a Postman representing a re-constituted United States. Due to his convincing acting, he doesn't actually become POTUS. But, eventually,

> he unwittingly inspires hope through an empty promise of a "Restored United States of America". The myth of the reconstituted U.S. grows and becomes its own reality driving the actual rebuilding of the country.

Below is a picture of the movie playbill.

[image]

Comment: Doesn’t match the description, and the OP said this isn’t it.